# what CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection cardinality is?

Tags: java, apache

I wanted to test equality between 2 list and found CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection. It says on API:
Returns true iff the given Collections contain exactly the same elements with exactly the same cardinalities.

what cardinalities exactly are? I couldn't find good explanation about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) page on set's cardinality, I expect it simply means the size. In this case it might also imply the order though...

Answer (score 14):

Based on [`CollectionUtils.cardinality()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#cardinality(O,%20java.lang.Iterable)):

> Returns the number of occurrences of `obj` in `coll`.

I'd say it returns true if and only if they have the same elements, the same number of times.

Take a look [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html), around line 514. It seems the order of the elements doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!